# How can I combine a union query with a max query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

First of all, my data is gathered from the following tables:

- tblProjects (fields `ProjectID`(key) and `ProjectTitle`)
- tblDocuments (fields `ProjectID`(linked), `DocID`(key) and `DocTitle`)
- tblRevisions (fields `DocID`(linked), `SubDate`, `Rev` and `ReturnDate`)

My goal is to combine the results of the below mentioned **A** (a UNION query) and **B** (a MAX query), and to make them work together (see **C**):

### A) The union query:

**SQL code:**

```
    SELECT ProjectID,0 as [0/DocID],ProjectTitle
    FROM tblProjects

    UNION ALL SELECT ProjectID,DocID,DocTitle
    FROM tblDocuments

    ORDER BY ProjectID, [0/DocID];
```

**RESULT:**

```
    ProjectID    | 0/DocID | Project/DocTitle 
    ------------------------------------------
    1            | 0       | Project 1        
    1            | 1       | Document 1.1     
    1            | 2       | Document 1.2
    2            | 0       | Project 2
    2            | 3       | Document 2.1
    2            | 4       | Document 2.2
```

---

### B) The max query:

**SQL code:**

```
    SELECT tblDocuments.DocID, Max(tblRevisions.SubDate) AS MaxOfSubDate
    FROM tblDocuments LEFT JOIN tblRevisions ON tblDocuments.DocID = tblRevisions.DocID
    GROUP BY tblDocuments.DocID;
```

**RESULT:**

```
    DocID    | MaxOfSubDate 
    -----------------------
    1        | 22.02.2016        
    2        | 20.02.2016     
    3        | (blank)
    4        | 21.02.2016
```

---

### C) Combining A and B:

(NB! I do not necessarily mean I want to compile the code from A and B into one single query. It could also be through a set of different queries: i.e. a third query which gathers data from A and B).

**SQL code:**

```
    ? I have absolutely no clue ?
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
    ProjectID    | 0/DocID | Project/DocTitle | MaxOfSubDate | Rev  | ReturnDate 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1            | 0       | Project 1        | 0            |      | 
    1            | 1       | Document 1.1     | 12.02.2016   |  03  | 22.02.2016
    1            | 2       | Document 1.2     | 10.02.2016   |  04  | 15.02.2016
    2            | 0       | Project 2        | 0            |      |
    2            | 3       | Document 2.1     | (blank)      | (bl) | (blank)
    2            | 4       | Document 2.2     | 21.02.2016   |  02  | (blank)
```

- Note: the fields `Rev` and `ClientRev` listed above comes from tblRevisions. I have to add these (and a few more) fields from tblRevisions into the mix somehow. In one of the queries? / perhaps in query B somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do exactly what you said. Create your first query A and your second query B and then create a third query C that will join the two results.

```
SELECT A.*, B.MaxOfSubDate, B.MaxOfOurRev, B.MaxOfClientRev
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B On A.[0/DocID] = B.DocID
```

Comment: Woops. It seems I may have oversimplified my question. `SubDate` is not the only field I want to get from tblRevisions. I also want to get the corresponding (only the latest) `OurRev` and `ClientRev` fields from that table.

Comment: I think you should be able to add Max(OurRev) and Max(ClientRev) to the SELECT clause. Then, in query C, select those additional columns from B.

Comment: Looks like I'm still simplifying it too much. Sorry for not having given you the full picture. Hard to find the balance between including _enough_ info, yet keeping it "short and simple". I really need to look up the fields _corresponding to_ Max(OurRev). Unfortunately I can't run a max lookup on each one. Reason is that I also have fields like `SubCode`, `ReturnDate`, `ReturnCode` and `Comments` in my tblRevisions. Since they will be filled in at different times (or not at all), I can't just search for each fields' max value.

Comment: Sorry man, you're on your own at this point. Unless you post all of the table structure and desire results with some sample data, you can't very well expect someone to help you figure out your problem. You keep adding complexity each time I respond. Good luck.

Comment: I'm so sorry @randyh22. My intention was to avoid adding in too much clutter, but I ended up leaving out crucial information. I understand your frustration fully. Nevertheless, your input was what I needed to point me in the right direction! I made myself yet another query to look up the fields _corresponding to_ Max(OurRev) and then did as you said: combined A and "the new B" to get C. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Hey man, no problem. I am glad I was able to get you going in the right direction. Sometimes it is better to have to figure some stuff out on your own anyway. You learn much more that way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new query (B2) that asks for tblRevisions' **correlating data** to query B's `maxOfSubDate`.
Query B2: "qryLatestRevDetailsAll" (created using design view):

```
SELECT tblDocuments.DocID, tblDocuments.DocTitle, tblDocuments.OurDocNo, tblDocuments.ClientDocNo, tblRevisions.OurRev, tblRevisions.ClientRev, tblRevisions.SubDate, tblRevisions.SubCode, tblRevisions.RetDate, tblRevisions.RetCode, tblRevisions.Comments, tblRevisions.Field1
FROM tblProjects 
INNER JOIN ((qryMAXSubDate 
  INNER JOIN tblDocuments ON qryMAXSubDate.DocID = tblDocuments.DocID) 
  INNER JOIN tblRevisions ON (qryMAXSubDate.MaxOfSubDate = tblRevisions.SubDate) 
  AND (tblDocuments.DocID = tblRevisions.DocID)) ON tblProjects.ProjectID = tblDocuments.ProjectID;
```

Step 2: combine the union query (A) with B2:

```
 SELECT quniProjectsDocuments.ProjectID, quniProjectsDocuments.[0/DocID], quniProjectsDocuments.ProjectTitle, quniProjectsDocuments.OurDocNo, quniProjectsDocuments.ClientDocNo, [qryLatestRevDetailsAll].OurRev, [qryLatestRevDetailsAll].SubDate, [qryLatestRevDetailsAll].RetDate
 FROM quniProjectsDocuments 
 LEFT JOIN qryLatestRevDetailsAll ON quniProjectsDocuments.[0/DocID]=[qryLatestRevDetailsAll].DocID
 ORDER BY quniProjectsDocuments.ProjectID, quniProjectsDocuments.[0/DocID];
```

Thanks a lot to @randyh22 for pointing me in the right direction!